# Pointers in python, v+=[] vs. v=v+[]

Tags: python, memory, operators

I am sorry if this question is replied somewhere since python (2.7) is a huge topic here, but I am not sure how to even look for it.
I am having this code.

```
>>> v=[1,2,3]
>>> f=v
>>> v+=[]
>>> f is v
True
>>> v=v+[]
>>> f is v
False
```

Could explain to me why `+=` operator is different from `v=v+`? Why does the first one doesn't create a new object in memory whereas another does although they are bound to be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `v=v+[]`, you are assigning a new list `v+[]` to `v`. Check out its `id`:

```
>>> v = [1,2,3]
>>> f=v
>>> id(v)
35713992L
>>> v+=[]
>>> id(v)
35713992L
>>> v=v+[]
>>> id(v)
35692232L
```